# Django MySQL Add ForeignKey

Tags: mysql, sql, django, django-models

In Django when I change a column, regardless of its datatype, to a foreignkey reference, it doesn't seem to be working.  As an example:

**models.py From:**

```
company_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='Company ID', blank=True, null=True)
```

**models.py To:**

```
company_id = models.ForeignKey('TblCompanies', db_column='Company ID', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

When I makemigrations & migrate it shows as "OK"; no issues.  But when I check the DB, it doesn't show these changes as foreign keys, but instead indexes.

I'm not an SQL server guru by any means, but generally when I start apps *from scratch*, this is not a problem.  I would see foreign keys right away.  In the KEY_COLUMN_USAGE table I would see the associated reference_table _schema, table_name and column_name.

In this case I am converting a web site and am bringing over the data from the old SQL server.  In the above mentioned table and columns, they show as NULL.

What am I missing here?

Here is the output of CREATE TABLE `tbl Communications` which uses two foreign keys.  The reference tables SHOULD be `tbl Customers`.`Company ID` and `tbl Contacts`.`Contact ID`

```
    tbl Communications | CREATE TABLE `tbl Communications` (
  `Comm ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Contact ID` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `Rep` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DateTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Type` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Notes` longtext,
  `Task ID` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `Initiator` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Alert` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Date Entered` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `Company ID` int(11),
  KEY `Comm ID` (`Comm ID`),
  KEY `Contact ID` (`Contact ID`),
  KEY `DateTime` (`DateTime`),
  KEY `Task ID` (`Task ID`),
  KEY `tbl Communications_Company ID_2dac354a_uniq` (`Company ID`),
  KEY `tbl Communications_Contact ID_01d40200_uniq` (`Contact ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Answer (score 0):

why you set the columns by your self ??

the ForeignKey should be to other model

Comment: I'm not setting the column by myself.  Like I said, I set up the models.py and run makemigrations & migrate.

Comment: you can put you models.py file